# What causes a muscle to be unsteady?

Tags: neuroscience, neural-network, motor

I have noticed for myself that sometimes, certain muscles may become unsteady. Here are three examples:

1. Sometimes it is more difficult to hold my hand still in the air.
2. Another example is how my calf muscles are not able to extend smoothly--when they get to a certain point, it sort of spasms and it is difficult to just maintain a slow steady movement.
3. Just today I noticed my right thumb, when holding down on the touch pad left click button, tends to spasm--my left thumb doesn't feel this way.

I also don't believe this can be contributed to lack of motor coordination since I have good coordination to play guitar with the finger picking style and therefore my fingers should be quite dexterous.

Though I am not sure if the first example is related to the other two. I am more curious about my thumb spasming since it can affect my guitar playing.

Comment: Might be wise to ask this on biology.SE too. I can think of a few psychological sources of unsteadiness (e.g., stress, disorders, indecision/conflict), but I bet they'd know more about things you might be more curious about. Just make sure you consider [appropriate strategies for the touchy matter of cross-posting on SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75012/246931).

Comment: @NickStauner  think asking this from a muscle physiology perspective on Biology would be fine.  I think we can shed some light on the motor control end of things from this side, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, adrenalin reduces hand steadiness and increases anxiety <sup>(Basowitz, Korchin, Oken, Goldstein, & Gussack, 1956)</sup>, so other causes of anxiety seem likely to reduce steadiness by promoting the release of adrenalin. Next, here's an odd reference for a more voluntary psychopharmacological cause of hand-arm unsteadiness: drug abuse (including alcohol; <sup>[Kaur, Sandhu, & Sandhu, 2007](http://www.krepublishers.com/02-Journals/T-Anth/Anth-09-0-000-000-2007-Web/Anth-09-4-000-07-Abst-PDF/Anth-09-4-299-07-393-Kaur-Gaganpreet/Anth-09-4-299-07-393-Kaur-G-Tt.pdf))</sup>. Caffeine and nicotine both impair hand steadiness, apparently without interacting <sup>(Smith, Tong,  & Leigh, 1977; Heatherley, Hayward, Seers, & Rogers, 2005; Rogers et al., 2005; Richardson, Rogers, Elliman, & O'Dell, 1995; Bovim, Næss, Helle, & Sand, 1995;</sup> see also for a review of caffeine effects and original evidence of a lack of interactions with alcohol  <sup>Franks, Hagedorn, Hensley, Hensley,  & Starmer, 1975)</sup>. Daily consumption of caffeine does not appear related though, and the effect of active caffeine can be blocked medically <sup>(Arnold, Springer, Engel, & Helveston, 1993)</sup>. A small dose of [propranolol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propranolol) may also reduce hand tremors regardless of caffeine use <sup>(Humayun, Rader, Pieramici, Awh, & de Juan, 1997)</sup>, though interested readers should consider [precautions and contraindications regarding propranolol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propranolol#Precautions_and_contraindications), including [hypoglycaemia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypoglycaemia) or diabetes, asthma, and abnormal blood pressure, among several others <sup>(Rossi, 2006)</sup>.

Physical exertion <sup>(Mürbe et al., 2001; Simon & Dare, 1965; [Halliday & Redfearn, 1956](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1359164/pdf/jphysiol01371-0105.pdf))</sup>, skill in manual labor, and sex <sup>(Gray, Sustare, & Thompson, 1953)</sup> appear relevant as well. Gray and colleagues found greater hand steadiness in men, but a more recent study found the opposite, except in women during premenstrual phases and women using oral contraceptives <sup>(Hudgens, Fatkin, Billingsley, & Mazurczak, 1988)</sup>. A loosely related sex difference emerged in a study of marksmanship, suggesting men's accuracy endures longer than women's <sup>(Johnson & Merullo, 1996)</sup>; incidentally, this study found no effect of caffeine on marksmanship. Also, another study found lesser effects of caffeine on motor performance in women who use caffeine regularly <sup>(Jacobson & Thurman-Lacey, 1992)</sup>. A particularly old study seems to have found a weakly negative (and quite possibly spurious) correlation between performance on a mental multiplication test and hand steadiness, as well as a positive experimental effect of humidity <sup>([Stecher, 1916](http://books.google.com/books?id=7uU-AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA59&lpg=PA59&dq=hand+steadiness+psychology&source=bl&ots=puFuottF4N&sig=q072lzSHPezfKU-AFH4lnANfNdw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=oqgDU_DMA8Ks2gWziYDQDw&ved=0CGwQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=hand%20steadiness%20psychology&f=false))</sup>.

An early [electroencephalographic (EEG)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroencephalography) study emphasized the distinction between low-frequency, high-amplitude tremors, and the opposite kind, suggesting that the latter is less affected by cortical activity <sup>(Lindqvist, 1941)</sup>. Two relatively recent studies produced apparently conflicting evidence about the relationship between hand and finger tremors and EEG activity: one succeeded <sup>(Isokawa & Komisaruk, 1983)</sup> and another failed to influence hand tremors with rhythmic flashes of light, even though this induced changes in EEG activity <sup>(Lakie & Combes, 1999)</sup>. Other articles on hand steadiness research have been published in psychological journals to which I don't have access; the first of these even considers personality factors such as [extraversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraversion_and_introversion) <sup>([Treadwell, 1960](http://books.google.com/books?id=AVUiAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA174&lpg=PA174&dq=hand+steadiness+psychology&source=bl&ots=7SCJyldgsc&sig=CKpMN-e5g3cMjMxBiWNORExn658&hl=en&sa=X&ei=oqgDU_DMA8Ks2gWziYDQDw&ved=0CG4Q6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=hand%20steadiness%20psychology&f=false); Fleishman, 1956; Lovell, 1941)</sup>.

Last (for this edition of this answer), some evidence supports the effectiveness of yoga for hand steadiness <sup>([Telles, Hanumanthaiah, Nagarathna, & Nagendra, 1994](http://www.libraryofyoga.com:8080/bitstream/handle/123456789/60/II.1994.15.pdf?sequence=1))</sup>, finger flexibility, grip strength and endurance <sup>(Garfinkel, Schumacher, Husain, Levy, & Reshetar, 1994; [Madanmohan, Jatiya, Udupa, & Bhavanani, 2003](http://icyer.com/documents/18.pdf); [Dash & Telles, 2001](http://yoga4arthritis.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/20010101_ihgsnvrapfyt.pdf); [Madanmohan et al., 1992](http://www.ijpp.com/IJPP%20archives/1992_36_4/229-233.pdf); [Raghuraj, Nagarathna, Nagendra, & Telles, 1997](http://ow.ly/tL6NG); [Raghuraj & Telles, 1997](http://www.libraryofyoga.com:8080/bitstream/handle/123456789/57/II.1997.25.doc?sequence=1))</sup>, and stability of knee extensors <sup>(Bukowski, Conway, Glentz, Kurland, & Galantino, 2006)</sup>. These references were cited in a recent review that deserves mention itself <sup>([Donahoe-Fillmore, Brahler, Fisher, & Beasley, 2010](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/232207909_The_Effect_of_Yoga_Postures_on_Balance_Flexibility_and_Strength_in_Healthy_High_School_Females/file/72e7e515448e1c52be.pdf))</sup>.

**References**

<sup>- Arnold, R. W., Springer, D. T., Engel, W. K., & Helveston, E. M. (1993). The effect of wrist rest, caffeine, and oral timolol on the hand steadiness of ophthalmologists. *Annals of Ophthalmology, 25*(7), 250–253.

- Basowitz, H., Korchin, S. J., Oken, D., Goldstein, M. S., & Gussack, H. (1956). Anxiety and performance changes with minimal dose of epinephrine. *AMA Archives of Neurology & Psychiatry, 76*(1), 98–105.

- Bovim, G., Næss, P., Helle, J., & Sand, T. (1995). Caffeine influence on the motor steadiness battery in neuropsychological tests. *Journal of Clinical and Experimental Neuropsychology, 17*(3), 472–476.

- Bukowski, E. L., Conway, A., Glentz, L. A., Kurland, K., & Galantino, M. L. (2006). The effect of iyengar yoga and strengthening exercises for people living with osteoarthritis of the knee: A case series. *International Quarterly of Community Health Education, 26*(3), 287–305.

- Dash, M., & Telles, S. (2001). Improvement in hand grip strength in normal volunteers and rheumatoid arthritis patients following yoga training. *Indian Journal of Physiology and Pharmacology, 45*(3), 355–360. Retrieved from http://yoga4arthritis.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/20010101_ihgsnvrapfyt.pdf.

- Donahoe-Fillmore, B., Brahler, C. J., Fisher, M. I., & Beasley, K. (2010). The effect of yoga postures on balance, flexibility, and strength in healthy high school females. *Journal of Women’s Health Physical Therapy, 34*(1), 10–17. Retrieved from http://www.researchgate.net/publication/232207909_The_Effect_of_Yoga_Postures_on_Balance_Flexibility_and_Strength_in_Healthy_High_School_Females/file/72e7e515448e1c52be.pdf.

- Franks, H. M., Hagedorn, H., Hensley, V. R., Hensley, W. J., & Starmer, G. A. (1975). The effect of caffeine on human performance, alone and in combination with ethanol. *Psychopharmacologia, 45*(2), 177–181.

- Fleishman, E. A. (1956). Psychomotor selection tests: Research and application in the United States Air Force. *Personnel Psychology, 9*(4), 449–467.

- Garfinkel, M. S., Schumacher Jr., H. R., Husain, A. B. I. D., Levy, M., & Reshetar, R. A. (1994). Evaluation of a yoga based regimen for treatment of osteoarthritis of the hands. *The Journal of Rheumatology, 21*(12), 2341–2343.

- Gray, J. S., Sustare, G., & Thompson, A. (1953). An apparatus for measuring operational hand steadiness. *Journal of Applied Psychology, 37*(1), 57–58.

- Halliday, A. M., & Redfearn, J. W. T. (1956). An analysis of the frequencies of finger tremor in healthy subjects. *The Journal of Physiology, 134*(3), 600–611. Retrieved from http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1359164/pdf/jphysiol01371-0105.pdf.

- Heatherley, S. V., Hayward, R. C., Seers, H. E., & Rogers, P. J. (2005). Cognitive and psychomotor performance, mood, and pressor effects of caffeine after 4, 6 and 8 h caffeine abstinence. *Psychopharmacology, 178*(4), 461–470.

- Hudgens, G. A., Fatkin, L. T., Billingsley, P. A., & Mazurczak, J. (1988). Hand steadiness: effects of sex, menstrual phase, oral contraceptives, practice, and handgun weight. *Human Factors: The Journal of the Human Factors and Ergonomics Society, 30*(1), 51–60.

- Humayun, M. U., Rader, R. S., Pieramici, D. J., Awh, C. C., & de Juan, E. (1997). Quantitative measurement of the effects of caffeine and propranolol on surgeon hand tremor. *Archives of Ophthalmology, 115*(3), 371–374.

- Isokawa, M., & Komisaruk, B. R. (1983). Convergence of finger tremor and EEG rhythm at the alpha frequency induced by rhythmical photic stimulation. *Electroencephalography and Clinical Neurophysiology, 55*(5), 580–585.

- Jacobson, B. H., & Thurman-Lacey, S. R. (1992). Effect of caffeine on motor performance by caffeine-naïve and familiar subjects. *Perceptual and Motor Skills, 74*(1), 151–157.

- Johnson, R. F., & Merullo, D. J. (1996). Effects of caffeine and gender on vigilance and marksmanship. *Proceedings of the Human Factors and Ergonomics Society Annual Meeting, 40*(23), 1217–1221.

- Kaur, G., Sandhu, S. S., & Sandhu, J. S. (2007). Comparison of arm-hand steadiness for shooting perfection in armed forces and Punjab police. *Anthropologist, 9*(4), 299–304. Retrieved from http://www.krepublishers.com/02-Journals/T-Anth/Anth-09-0-000-000-2007-Web/Anth-09-4-000-07-Abst-PDF/Anth-09-4-299-07-393-Kaur-Gaganpreet/Anth-09-4-299-07-393-Kaur-G-Tt.pdf.

- Lakie, M., & Combes, N. (1999). The phase of postural hand tremor is not influenced by repetitive photic brain stimulation. *Clinical Neurophysiology, 110*(12), 2020–2025.

- Lindqvist, T. (1941). Finger tremor and the α‐waves of the electro‐encephalogram. *Acta Medica Scandinavica, 108*(6), 580–585.

- Lovell, C. (1941). A study of personal variation in hand-arm steadiness. *The American Journal of Psychology, 54*(2), 230–236.

- Madanmohan, Jatiya, L., Udupa, K., & Bhavanani, A. B. (2003). Effect of yoga training on handgrip, respiratory pressures and pulmonary function. *Indian Journal of Physiology and Pharmacology, 47*(4), 387–392. Retrieved from http://icyer.com/documents/18.pdf.

- Madanmohan, Thombre, D. P., Bharathi, B., Nambinarayan, T. K., Thakur, S., Krishnamurthy, N., & Chandrabose, A. (1992). Effect of yoga training on reaction time, respiratory endurance and muscle strength. *Indian Journal of Physiology and Pharmacology, 36*, 229–233. Retrieved from http://www.ijpp.com/IJPP%20archives/1992_36_4/229-233.pdf.

- Mürbe, D., Hüttenbrink, K. B., Zahnert, T., Vogel, U., Tassabehji, M., Kuhlisch, E., & Hofmann, G. (2001). Tremor in otosurgery: Influence of physical strain on hand steadiness. *Otology & Neurotology, 22*(5), 672–677.

- Raghuraj, P., Nagarathna, R., Nagendra, H. R., & Telles, S. (1997). Pranayama increases grip strength without lateralized effects. *Indian Journal of Physiology and Pharmacology, 41*(2), 129–133. Retrieved from http://ow.ly/tL6NG.

- Raghuraj, P., & Telles, S. (1997). Muscle power, dexterity skill and visual perception in community home girls trained yoga or sports and in regular school girls. *Indian Journal of Physiology and Pharmacology, 41*(4), 409–415. Retrieved from http://www.libraryofyoga.com:8080/bitstream/handle/123456789/57/II.1997.25.doc?sequence=1.

- Richardson, N. J., Rogers, P. J., Elliman, N. A., & O'Dell, R. J. (1995). Mood and performance effects of caffeine in relation to acute and chronic caffeine deprivation. *Pharmacology Biochemistry and Behavior, 52*(2), 313–320.

- Rogers, P. J., Heatherley, S. V., Hayward, R. C., Seers, H. E., Hill, J., & Kane, M. (2005). Effects of caffeine and caffeine withdrawal on mood and cognitive performance degraded by sleep restriction. *Psychopharmacology, 179*(4), 742–752.

- Rossi, S. (Ed., 2006). *Australian Medicines Handbook*. Adelaide.

- Simon, J. R., & Dare, C. E. (1965). Effects of physical exercise on hand steadiness. *The Laryngoscope, 75*(11), 1737–1740.

- Smith, D. L., Tong, J. E., & Leigh, G. (1977). Combined effects of tobacco and caffeine on the components of choice reaction-time, heart rate, and hand steadiness. *Perceptual and Motor Skills, 45*(2), 635–639.

- Stecher, L. I. (1916). The effect of humidity on nervousness and on general efficiency. In R. S. Woodworth (Ed.), *Archives of Psychology*, No. 38, pp. 40–65. New York: The Science Press / Columbia University. Retrieved from [Google Books](http://books.google.com/books?id=7uU-AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA59&lpg=PA59&dq=hand+steadiness+psychology&source=bl&ots=puFuottF4N&sig=q072lzSHPezfKU-AFH4lnANfNdw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=oqgDU_DMA8Ks2gWziYDQDw&ved=0CGwQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=hand%20steadiness%20psychology&f=false).

- Telles, S., Hanumanthaiah, B. H., Nagarathna, R., & Nagendra, H. R. (1994). Plasticity of motor control systems demonstrated by yoga training. *Indian Journal of Physiology and Pharmacology, 38*(2), 143–144. Retrieved from http://www.libraryofyoga.com:8080/bitstream/handle/123456789/60/II.1994.15.pdf?sequence=1.

- Treadwell, E. (1960). The effects of depressant drugs on vigilance and psychomotor performance. *Experiments in Personality, 1*, 159–196. An alternate publication can be previewed through [Google Books](http://books.google.com/books?id=AVUiAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA174&lpg=PA174&dq=hand+steadiness+psychology&source=bl&ots=7SCJyldgsc&sig=CKpMN-e5g3cMjMxBiWNORExn658&hl=en&sa=X&ei=oqgDU_DMA8Ks2gWziYDQDw&ved=0CG4Q6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=hand%20steadiness%20psychology&f=false).</sup>